# Form Submission to Spreadsheet event data

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using a form to submit data to a spreadsheet. I am attempting to use information in the form submission event in a script attached to my spreadsheet. I have the form submission trigger setup and am able to log event info in the logs with:

```
var dataRange = e.range;
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(dataRange.getA1Notation()))
```

This logs `"A30:F30"`
But I can't seem to store this info in a variable.

For example,

```
var dataRange = e.range;
let info = JSON.stringify(dataRange.getA1Notation())
     
return info;
```

this returns `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined`

All the docs have Logger.log to see event data, but I want to use the info in my script. Why can I only see it in the logs?

Comment: This is rather wierd `JSON.stringify(dataRange.getA1Notation()` because dataRange.getA1Notation()  returns a string.  So what's the point?  Why not just do `let info=dataRange.getA1Notation();`

Comment: `function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast(e.range.getA1Notation());
}`

Comment: If I do `let info = dataRange.getA1Notation();` I get the same can't read property of 'range'.

Answer (score 0):

### Once you use the `return` statement you exit the function that is being triggered on form submit

- Since this function is called on trigger rather from another function - you are not returning your `info` anywhere
- If you want to store the value to use in another function - use [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties())
- This allows you to store variables / values for an indefinite amount of time and make them accessible to any dunction within the given script.

Sample:

```js
var dataRange = e.range;
let info = JSON.stringify(dataRange.getA1Notation())
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.setProperty("rangeNotation", info);
```

To retrieve the stored property:

```js
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var info = scriptProperties.getProperty("rangeNotation");
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will play with this.